# How to place files outside app deployment directory in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In AWS EB, how to place my **environment.properties** (contains app runtime config like port, logs dir, DB info, security keys, etc.) under ***/var/env_config/myapp***, so it can be referred by the app at runtime?

Though my further plan is to put this *environment.properties* in a secure non app directory of local or remote file system as it contains sensitive information.

```
global.env = propsReader(path.join(process.env.ENV_PATH, 'env-main.properties'));
```

On the EB, I have added an Environment property 'ENV_PATH = /var/env_config/myapp'

EB logs:

```
web: > myapp@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
web: > node src/app-main.js
web: 8266 [
web: '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.18.1-linux-x64/bin/node',
web: '/var/app/current/src/app-main.js'
web: ]
web: /var/env_config/myapp
web: internal/fs/utils.js:230
web: throw err;
web: ^
web: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/env_config/myapp/env-main.properties'
```

I just wanna deploy my application in the same fashion in AWS EB or Docker or VM or local machine, with just an environment property saying where the required runtime input files are.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> How to access Elastic Beanstalk file system to configure my .properties file?

Not sure what do you mean by "accessing file system", but usually you would create `.ebextensions` folder in your project directory. The extensions are commonly used for **running commands or scripts** when you are deploying your app. There are special sections for that:

- [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands): You can use the commands key to execute commands on the EC2 instance. The commands run **before** the application and web server are set up and the application version file is extracted.
- [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands): You can use the container_commands key to execute commands that affect your application source code. Container commands run **after** the application and web server have been set up and the application version archive has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed.

Therefore, you could use the above sections to **modify your `.properties`** file during deployment of your application into EB.

Comment: Is it through S3 console, I need to add the folder structure **/var/env_config/myapp** and upload **environment.properties** under the S3 Bucket for my EB env?

Comment: @VisvM In your deployment folder, before you upload your application to EB, you should create `.ebextensions` folder, and place EB specific scripts there. The scripts would be automatically executed on the EB instances during deployment. Thus, you would write the scripts to create any files or folders your application needs.